# HTTP authentication and PHP authentication

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP authentication using PHP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074409/http-authentication-using-php-authentication)

Hi.
I'm making a members area for my site and I have it already running. I authenticate members using mysql and php and this works really well.

But now problems occurs, I would like to offer members a possibility to upload files to the systems, and those files should be available ONLY to logged in members.

I know I could store those files to a database or even in a filesystem and serve them throught php, BUT this will get very heavy for the server when members upload bigger files. Those files might be even 20MB or even bigger.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?  How to secure access to the files, or how to store them on your server?

Comment: @Eric, damn, you beat me by 4 seconds!

Comment: Don't accept sizes over a certain limit? Or upgrade your hosting plan?

Comment: Or you could try amazon cloud hosting http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/ or your prefered cloud hosting to store the files

Answer (score 1):

His question is how to make those files unavailable to users who are not authenticated (I supppose).

Storing files themselves in databases is a very bad idea. Just put them in an unaccessible directory (ie: use .htaccess to restric access) and serve them using PHP. The additional load on the server in doing so (if done correctly) is minimal.

Comment: "The additional load on the server in doing so (if done correctly) is minimal." How would one do this correctly?