# HTTP authentication using PHP authentication

Tags: php, javascript

I'm making a members area for my site and I have it already running. I authenticate members using mysql and php and this works really well.

But now problems occurs, I would like to offer members a possibility to upload files to the systems, and those files should be available ONLY to logged in members.

I know I could store those files to a database or even in a filesystem and serve them throught php, BUT this will get very heavy for the server when members upload bigger files. Those files might be even 20MB or even bigger.

I would like to let apache serve the files, but just need to find a way to automatically do the http authentication, so users wouldn't need to log in twice. I suppose it is ok to make this http authentication behind one username and password, something like when a user logs in to the php and mysql authentication, transparently at the same time javascript etc. would do that http authentication also, every member would do the http authentication with the same credentials. Of course I wouldn't want to store those http auth credentials in a javascript file, but something ajax like solution maybe would do the trick. I'm just not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are confusing authentication (where you provide some way to login) with HTTP authentication (where you specifically use the HTTP protocol to authenticate, and the browser shows a popup to the user).

You probably want the former so you can style the login page. In that case you'll have to use PHP or some scripting langauge to check that the user is logged in. [fpassthru](http://php.net/fpassthru) or [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) can be good solutions for some web sites; they're fast and optimised for this type of work.

If you really want to do the file handling work in the web browser and not in PHP, one solution can be to create unique, short-lived filenames. You can for example create hard links to the file in PHP using [link](http://php.net/link) and then redirect the user to the temporary filename. Store the hard links in a database and remove them after a short while.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Using PHP/Apache to restrict access to static files (html, css, img, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187200/using-php-apache-to-restrict-access-to-static-files-html-css-img-etc). I think the approach taken there is pretty similar to your problem.